# How to estimate with confidence the quantiles of an unknown random variable using sample mean and variance?

Tags: estimation, sampling, nonparametric, quantiles

Let $X$ be a uniform distribution of inputs to be used for sampling. Let $f(x)$ be an expensive function. If we take samples from $X$ and give them as input to $f$ we get outputs $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n$ from some mystery distribution $Y$ with finite support. I wish to calculate the minimum of $Y$ with, say, 95% confidence. Alternatively, something like, say, the 5th percentile with 95% confidence.

The two methods I know of are Chebyshev's inequality and Wilks' method. For the Chebyshev's inequality, I don't know which variant to use. [This one shown on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Finite_samples) appears to be the closest to what I want, but it is two-tailed. [Wilks' method](http://openturns.github.io/openturns/master/theory/data_analysis/quantile_estimation_wilks.html) seems more promising, but it appears to be very conservative.

What method would you recommend?

Comment: Is $f(x)$ a monotonic function? If so, the answer is available immediately without any approximation. In any case, you have the whole distribution of $y_i$, not just sample mean and variance, so appoximations based only on mean and variance are not optimal.

Comment: $f(x)$ is not monotonic. And yes, I guess I have the entire sample distribution of $Y$. Does that make things better?

Comment: Are you really after quantiles (as in your question) or are you after tail probabilities (as in the Wikipedia method you link to). If you do want quantiles, then which ones exactly? If you want a tail probability, then which one exactly? In either case, having the entire sample distribution helps considerably.

Comment: What I really need is a guarantee on the minimum value of $Y$ ($Y$ has finite support). Since I have a limited number of samples, I would like to use the samples to calculate the minimum value of $Y$ along with the confidence in that minimum. Ideally I would like to use the samples along with the desired confidence to calculate the minimum.

Comment: Mmm. That's a very different (and much harder) problem to that which your question seems to be asking. I suggest editing your question to make your aims clearer.

Comment: The sample minimum of the $y_i$ is obviously a consistent but biased estimator for the minimum of $Y$. I don't know of a rigorous way to improve on that without making assumptions about the unknown distribution of $Y$.

Comment: That is why I was seeking, say, the 5th percentile, with 95% confidence, which would still be helpful if I can get that instead of the minimum.

Comment: Under the stated conditions, the *only* guarantee is that the minimum does not exceed any of the observations.  Nothing else can be deduced without additional assumptions.

Comment: @whuber this minimum is the sample minimum? Or the minimum from some statistical formula? What additional assumptions would help?

Comment: To estimate quantiles of the theoretical distribution, you simply use the corresponding quantiles of the sample distribution. Specifying a 95% confidence interval however can't be done without more assumptions.

Comment: Because you explicitly posit a nonparametric setting (all you assume is "some mystery distribution"), no "statistical formula" is available.  You can make progress only by making restrictive assumptions about that distribution.  An example would be to suppose it is a shifted Lognormal, for instance.  (This is just an example, not a suggestion!)